# jQuery - effect elements taken from an array (individually)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="objectA"></div>
<div class="objectB"></div>
<div class="objectA"></div>
<div class="objectB"></div>
```

When i use this script nothing happens:

```
var allObjects = $("div[class^=object]");
allObjects[1].fadeIn();
```

But when i use this script, the alert message will be 4, and it will fade all the elements:

```
var allObjects = $("div[class^=object]");
    allObjects.fadeIn();
    alert(allObjects.lenght);
```

so i know i got the elements i wanted into an array, but how can i effect each 1 individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allObjects[1]` returns a raw DOM element.  DOM elements do not have a `fadeIn` method, jquery objects do.  Instead, use `.eq`:

```
allObjects.eq(1).fadeIn();
```

`.eq` return a jquery object containing the nth element.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over each element individually with jQuery.each(). See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rQck/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allObjects = $("div[class^='object']");
    $(allObjects[1]).fadeIn();
})
```